# What cause the OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space? MemoryAnalyzer shows the JNI local reference as the GC Root

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, apache-tomee, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I am running a test suite(Many test cases,  with TestNG framework) on apache-tomee, which requires deploying and undeploying very frequently. but unfortunately the Apache Tomee instance throws OOM before the test suite completes.

Jconsole show that the heap and non-heap memory usage would just grow and grow.

I use the Eclipse Memory Analyzer to analyze the HeapDump file, but found something odd:

[MemoryAnalyzer domainator_tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVXwn.png)

[Path to GC Root, all JNI Local reference....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOpFP.png)

I couldn't find out who is the GC Root of class TestNG And cause the OOM, we don't have any JNI Code.

The ThreadLocalMemoryLeakPreventionListener is configured to be Enabled.
Apache-TomEE with tomcat8.0.32
JDK1.7.0_67

add: When i switch to JDK1.7.0_80 things get better but still OOM finally. Memory Analyzer show the same thing.

Comment: The name `TaskThread` suggests a subclass of `Thread` and threads are reachable as long as they are alive. That might be represented by a “JNI Local” reference, but regardless of its representation, a thread is a gc root, by definition. And, of course, the class `TestNG` is reachable while the tests are still running. That shouldn’t surprise anyone. Well, that’s the reachability of one particular `TestNG`. You may check whether the other reference graphs look different. If not, you have quite a lot of threads…

Comment: But with the ThreadLocalMemoryLeakPreventionListener configured, TaskThread (worker thread of tomcat ThreadExecutor) will be destoryed  and rebuilt after each undeloyment. I suspect that some other objects might refer to the ClassLoader, but the MemoryAnalyzer show nothing special other than the JNI Local. @Holger

Comment: Maybe I misread the tree, it looks like the thread instances hold references to (mainly proxy) classes which are loaded through the same classloader as the `TestNG` class and that kind of reference is specified as “JNI Local”. There is no chance of finding the origin of that reference from that graph. But anyway, whatever “ThreadLocalMemoryLeakPreventionListener” does, these threads are obviously still alive…

Comment: By the way, why do you try to reload the TestNG framework at all? It would make more sense to reparate test suites and test framework and reload the test suites only…

Comment: @Holger, We use the arquillian to run tests, testcase were package into a WAR and deployed on apache-tomee server. org.testng.TestNG is packaged into the  WAR archive file to run the testcase.  the class TestNG was loaded by Web Application ClassLoader.
it seems like Arquillian-Protocol ==> testng ===> testcase

Comment: I think, it’s too broad to discuss the “how to” here, but it must be possible to reload the testcases without the need to reload testng.

Comment: yes, i should have a try. and maybe i should try to destroy these threads by force, they seems so odds.